# ionic 6 datepicker as popup as it used to be?

Tags: ionic-framework

I have just updated to ionic 6 and noticed the date picker sits inside the page as a full calendar, where it used to pop up on the bottom of the screen.

I can't figure out how to get it back to how it used to work, here is the code (this hasn't changed since the update to ionic 6):

```
<ion-datetime formControlName="dob" class="input" placeholder="Select date of birth..."></ion-datetime>
```

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iq_XIPml9_M Check this video. skip 12 minutes.

Comment: @NajamUsSaqib thanks but that's not what i mean. It used to pop up from the bottom of the phone like the native date picker, now it's this horrible calendar.

Comment: Yes i know,  Now ionic have updated their Datetime experience. You have to change your Application experience as well. Otherwise you should dwongrade to v5+. Otherwise i will suggest you to use Datetime Modals now for this as mentioned in video tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

It's still possible by using ion-popover.

```
<ion-item>
    <ion-label position="stacked">Date of birth</ion-label>
    <ion-input value="{{ user.birthDate | date: 'dd MMM yyyy' }}" id="date"></ion-input>
    <ion-popover trigger="date" >
        <ng-template>
            <ion-datetime presentation="date" [(ngModel)]="user.birthDate" locale="en-US"></ion-datetime>
        </ng-template>
    </ion-popover>
</ion-item>
```

[image: Example]

All credit to Damir Arh who posted the solution here: https://www.damirscorner.com/blog/posts/20220107-DatePickerPopupInIonic6.html